How to make SQLAlchemy AsyncSession generator?
I need class method to create sessions and if any exception raises to call "rollback()" func and "close()" session.
class DatabaseHelper:
    def __init__(
        self,
        url: str,
        echo: bool = False,
    ) -> None:
        self.engine = create_async_engine(
            url=url,
            echo=echo,
        )
        self.session_factory = async_sessionmaker(
            bind=self.engine,
        )

    async def get_session(self):
        # some code
        yield self.session_factory()

I tried to make it using this code but i got AttributeError: 'async_generator_asend' object has no attribute 'some attr'
main.py
async def main():
    session = db.get_session()
    group = await session.scalar(select(Group).where(Group.tg_id == 1))

Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pingvinus\Documents\Projects\telegram-bot-database\telegram_bot_database\test.py", line 63, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Pingvinus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pingvinus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pingvinus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pingvinus\Documents\Projects\telegram-bot-database\telegram_bot_database\test.py", line 49, in main
    group1 = await session.scalar(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'scalar'


Please include the full Traceback output which would narrow down the exact lines of code that resulted the issue; the question as-is may not be answerable as there is insufficient detail to reproduce the issue, please ensure a mvce is provided, or alternatively, follow the example as per documentation.

traceback provided. there is nothing in the documentation about asynchronous generators or automatic session closure

Seeing group1 = await session.scalar(... being the problematic line is a much better clue, but I am glad you were able to solve this.

I found the solution. Just use asynccontextmanager. Now it looks like:
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_session(self):
    session = self.session_factory()
    try:
        yield session
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await session.rollback()
    finally:
        await session.close()

And I can use it like I wanted:
async def main():
    session_gen = db.get_session()
    async with session_gen as session:
        group = await session.scalar(
            select(Group).where(Group.tg_id == 1),
        )

